# how can I go back to debug mode after releasing the app?

Tags: flutter, dart, debugging, release

I built my app by the release mode, and then I realized I couldn't use 'hot reload' and emulator in the release mode.

So I want to switch release mode to debug mode. but I don't know how.

I'm using android studio

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]  : here if --release is written in Additional run args then remove it will run in debuge mode after that.